# SrLua - Problema após compilar

Tags: lua

Estou tentando compilar um simples script que contém:

```
require 'classlib'
human = class()

function human:__init(name)
    self.name = name
end
gabriel = human("Gabriel")
print(gabriel.name)
```

Com o srlua, mas após compilar, quando tento executar, sempre da o erro:

> 1: Could not load package 'classlib' from path ';;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac

Executando o script pelo interpretador Lua, funciona normalmente.

Obs: todos os arquivos estão na mesma pasta(srlua, test.lua, classlib.lua)

> Package.path : `;.\?.lua;G:\PROGRAMACAO\srlua\lua\?.lua;G:\PROGRAMACAO\srlua\lua\?\init.lua;G:\PROGRAMACAO\srlua\?.lua;G:\PROGRAMACAO\srlua\?\init.lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac`

Comment: Baixei aqui: http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#srlua

Comment: Era 5.1. Acho que consegui resolver. Vou ver, e criar uma resposta.

Comment: Engano meu, continua sem solução :\

Comment: o seu Windows é x64 ou x86?

Comment: A mensagem que você mostra não vem de Lua.

Comment: X86. @lhf, sabe o que pode ser feito?

Comment: Me parece um erro de path. Imprima `package.path` antes de chamar `require`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Está la.

Answer (score 1):

Testei o programa com as versões: [lua-5.3.2](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html), [srlua-5.3.2](http://joedf.users.sourceforge.net/luabuilds/), [classlib 2.04.04](https://github.com/LuaDist/classlib); e não ocorreram erros.

Seguem os passos utilizados para compilar:

Arquivos:

```
C:\tmp\teste-lua>dir /b
classlib.lua
srlua.exe
test.lua
```

Para compilar:

`glue srlua.exe test.lua teste.exe`

Saída após a execução:

```
C:\tmp\teste-lua>teste
Gabriel
```

Ambiente: `Windows 8.1 64bit` com a variável `PATH` apontando para o diretório
base do interpretador Lua (o arquivo `glue.exe` foi colocado nesse mesmo diretório).

Por serem versões mais novas que as utilizadas na pergunta, talvez esse erro
tenha ocorrido devido a um bug que já foi corrigido.